# OSGi equinox bundle stays always in the state "RESOLVED"

Tags: osgi, bundle, lifecycle, equinox, p2

I've created one main bundle in which one I've installed the equinox p2. Then I export it to obtain an executable. My executable works correctly.

I've also created one other Bundle that interacts with the first one. In eclipse, if I create a product configuration with these 2 bundles and run the product, everything works.

After that, I export my second Bundle as a "deployable feature" and then I install this bundle wihtin my application via the "help->install new software". I'm able to install it, however my Bundle stays always in the state "RESOLVED" even if I restart my application. I'd like to set the state as "ACTIVE".

Do you know if I can configure somehting to autostart my bundle as I did in my "Product configuration"? Or is there an another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start your bundle manually with the commandline command "start ". It seems that there are some problems in BundleActivator of your bundle. You should get some logs (errors/warnings).

Answer (score 1):

The RESOLVED state is not an error state, it simply means nobody has activated your bundle. Why do you need it to be ACTIVE? Is there some other error caused by the fact that it is not ACTIVE?

Otherwise, if your application is working then just don't worry about it.